# managed cookie in cordova with android

Tags: android, cordova, cookies

I have made an application for android with cordova, the homepage is in local and calls to web services through jQuery. The app has a plugin to view a PDF.

Now we want to see a PDF, but to see the pdf need to be log on the server. The login process done with jQuery and it works. Once we log on the server we can call services that require login.

The problem is that we want to retrieve a PDF that requires login, but the http session is not shared from jquery to cordova plugin (or webview). The request on the server is like a not log user.

We tried to recover PDFs do not need login and it works.

The plugin used is based on http://call-me-early.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/android-webview-download-pdf-generated.html

¿Any ideas?

We have tried to retrieve the pdf with jquery and pass the array of bytes to the plugin but does not work.
Another idea is to move the contents of the jquery's cookie to the plugin, but we can not get this cookie

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. What we do is capture the cookie in the call (in success) that creates the session on the server. We keep the cookie locally and then send it to open the PDF plugin, this plugin adds the cookie to the call that makes the native part.

JS part:

```
success: _.bind(function(data, textStatus, request){
    var header = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
    console.log("header: "+header);
    var match = header.match(/(Set-Cookie|set-cookie|Set-cookie): (.+?);/);
    console.log("match: "+match);
    if(match!==undefined && match!==null && match.length>=3){
        console.log("CON COOKIE");
        console.log("COOKIE: "+match[2]);
        localStorage.setItem("miCookie",match[2]);
    }
},this),
```

Plugin call

```
function callShowPdfPluginAndroid( param ){
require(['utils'], function(utils) {
    utils.showLoading();
    return cordova.exec( function(){utils.hideLoading();}, 
        function(error){utils.hideLoading();nativePluginErrorHandler(error);}, 
        "NativeBridgeAndroid", 
        "ShowPdf", 
        [param,localStorage.getItem("miCookie")]);
});
}
```

Native:

```
URL u = new URL(params[0]);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();
```